# addthis open email share dialog manually

Tags: javascript, addthis

I have a set of share buttons that are added and removed dynamically from the DOM. Instead of telling addthis to 'intialize' each time one of these are added, I would like to have a way of doing something like:

`addthis.openEmailDialog([options]);`

Is something like this possible?

Comment: I thinl, best place to seek help on this is [AddThis API Doc](http://support.addthis.com/customer/portal/articles/381263-addthis-client-api).

Comment: I have already exhausted that option, the API doesn't seem to be targeted to flexible javascript integration. It relies heavily on a static DOM, and doesn't provide a nice JS api. So, the question would be if someone have found an alternative way something like this. It is quite unfortunate that they only provide such a basic functionality - evidently targeted to blogs and simple stuff - given that the send email part is quite impressive and I would really like to use it on my not-static-DOM app.

Comment: Have you found a solution / workaround / another tool to solve the problem Danc?

Comment: Oh, I have a vague memory on how I solved this, it's been a while now. IIRC I ended up repeating the DOM structure for each particular item I wanted to share. I have no clue if the API supports this now.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the AddThis javascript already loaded - you can add the class **`addthis_button_email`** to the `<a>` link:

```
<a href="#" class="addthis_button_email">Email this page</a>
```